# How can I create an infinite loop without killing program execution?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a program whose logic is the same as the dummy sample I've included here. I've tried a simply `while (1)` which doesn't run (at least the UI is not shown). This sample runs the `while` loop based on a variable setting which is changed by an `addEventListener()` which should terminate the loop. However, it acts just as the `while (1)`. Simply stated, what I need to do is wait for a password input and verify that it is a match. If not, I continue to loop. If it is a match, the program proceeds to another loop (not shown in the sample), which needs to run as long as the program runs. This second `while` runs several functions based on a user input. Each time there is a user input, another loop of the `while` is run. I prefer not using another thread. It seems any logic that creates a loop reacts the same way, i.e., no execution or at least no visible execution. Put another way, why doesn't `while (1)` or `for (;;)` work! Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
//app.js
var debugText = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    top: 600,
    left: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 100,
    color: '#777',
    font:{fontSize:40},
    hintText: 'debug text'
});
var entryCodeText = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top: 300,
    left: 0,
    width: 400,
    height: 100,
    color: '#777',
    font:{fontSize:40},
    hintText: 'Enter Passcode'
});

//add labels and fields to window
    win.add(entryCodeText);
    win.add(debugText);
    win.open();

while (exitCode == 0) {
    // do stuff
} // end of exitCode while loop
// start of continuous program loop
while (1) {
    // if no event, just continue loop
    // if event , execute several functions and continue with loop
} // end of while(1) loop - runs as long as program runs
//*************************************************************************
entryCodeText.addEventListener("return", function(e) {

    if (computeCode(entryCodeText.value)< 0) {
        debugText.text = "failed computecode";
        exitCode = 0;
        continue;
    } else {
        debugText.text = "passed computeCode()";
        exitCode = 1;
        break;
    }
});
//continue with other logic on break and exitCode = 1
//************************************************************
function computeCode(textValue) {
    // do stuff to the textValue
}
```

Comment: Generally, don't. Why do you need an infinite loop instead of just running some code in response to user input?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
```

Should make it run forever.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using the keyup or keydown evt.

**That said**, if you must do it this way, you can use the setTimeout Function.

In terms of script execution it always runs last, (even after the browsers internal UI operations) and therefore prevents the UI from locking up.

This example uses 2 text boxes. Once the first one has a correct value it moves into the inner loop.

```
<html>
  <body>
  UserName: <input type="text" id="txt" /><br>
  Password: <input type="text" id="txt2" />


<script>
    var txt =  document.getElementById('txt'),
        txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2');
    var loop, innerLoop;
    (function loop(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(txt.value === 'name'){
            alert('correct username entered');
                            //new loop
                (function innerLoop(){ 
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(txt2.value === 'password') {
                            alert('correct password entered');
                            return;
                        }
                        else setTimeout(innerLoop,0); 
                    },0);
                })();
                return;
            }
            else setTimeout(loop,0);
        },0);
    })();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vg5ND/